# Calculus limits please demonstrate question?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have been trouble doing some more difficult limits

I have these two examples from a teacher and think if i can just be shown the working and answer i should be fine from there out. Thanks for your help.

$(a)\; \lim\limits_{x\to-2}\dfrac{3x^2+8x+4}{2x^2+x-6} \\ \; \\ (b)\;\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{3x^4-11x^3+42x}{-15x^4+3x^2 +101}$

Comment: Try applying L'Hospital's Rule.

Comment: For a) use L'Hôspital's and for b) know your degree rules.

Comment: @bobby In the first one to get $\frac 0 0$. This means $x-(-2)$ is a factor of both the numerator and the denominator. Thus $$\dfrac{3x^2+8x+4}{2x^2+x-6}=\dfrac{(x+2)p(x)}{(x+2)q(x)},$$ for some polynomials $p$ and $q$. Find these polynomials. For the second one, divide by $x^4$ (which is the largest degree) on the top and on the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim\limits_{x\to-2}\dfrac{3x^2+8x+4}{2x^2+x-6} = \lim_{x\to -2} \dfrac{(3x+2)(x+2)}{(2x -3)(x+2)} = \lim_{x\to -2}\frac{3x+2}{2x-3} = \frac{-4}{-7}= \frac 47 $$

For the second limit, divide numerator and denominator by $x^4$, and evaluate.